# Filter different groups by different factor levels

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
set.seed(5)
df <- tibble(x=factor(rep(c(LETTERS,letters[1:12]),10)), y=sample(seq(1993,2000), 380, replace = T),z = sample(1:12, 380, replace = T))
```

Is there an easy way to filter this data frame to remain with `y>=1993` for level A, `y>=1994` for level B, `y>=1995` for level C, `y>=1996` for level D, `y>=1997` for level E, `y>=1993` for level F, `y>=1994` for level G, `y>=1995` for level a and the remaining levels `y>=2000` in column x using `dplyr` verbs?

Comment: Are they always only three levels?

Comment: No, I have more levels. Actually, I have 38 levels for x and I would like to filter based on different values of y

Comment: That makes the solution different. You can't just filter on 38 levels. Could you add sample data with `dput(head(df,n))` and more conditions?

Comment: I have now edited to include 38 levels with more conditions. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Please also set seed.

Comment: Sorry, that is now set.

Comment: Check my edit below. However,level A appears twice in your conditions. Please also see the notes in the answer.

Comment: I have **A** and **a** which I consider as different levels.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Check the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
 filter(ifelse(x=="A",y>=1993,ifelse(x=="B",
                                      y>=1994,y>=1995)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  x         y     z
  <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 A      1993     2
2 A      1994     3
3 A      1995     4
4 B      1994     7
5 B      1995     8
6 C      1995    12
```

Or using `case_when`:

```
df %>% 
   filter(case_when(x=="A" ~ y>=1993,
                    x=="B" ~ y>=1994,
                   TRUE ~ y>=1995))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  x         y     z
  <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 A      1993     2
2 A      1994     3
3 A      1995     4
4 B      1994     7
5 B      1995     8
6 C      1995    12
```

**EDIT**: With the updated data and conditions:

```
    set.seed(520)

   df %>% 
     filter(case_when(x %in% c("A","F") ~ y>=1993,
                     x %in% c("C","a") ~ y>=1995,
                      x=="D" ~ y>=1996,
                      x=="G"~ y>=1994,
                      x=="E" ~ y>= 1997,
                      TRUE ~ y>=2000))
    # A tibble: 90 x 3
       x         y     z
       <fct> <int> <int>
     1 A      1999     3
     2 C      1998     5
     3 F      1993     8
     4 G      1997     7
     5 H      2000     5
     6 K      2000     2
     7 P      2000     2
     8 V      2000     9
     9 W      2000     1
    10 g      2000     7
    # … with 80 more rows
```

**NOTES::**

1. Data: As is with seed set to 520
2. I find this approach a bit too manual. There might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using booleans with parentheses:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter((x == "A" & y >= 1993) | (x == "B" & y >= 1994) | (x == "C" & y >= 1995))

  x         y     z
  <fct> <dbl> <int>
1 A      1993     2
2 A      1994     3
3 A      1995     4
4 B      1994     7
5 B      1995     8
6 C      1995    12
```